# Send Curl Login infor as a GET or POST parameter

Tags: http, curl

I have the current URL curl -X GET http://domain.com/api/user/  -u username:password

If I send this over the terminal I get the JSON response for that API request if I don't add username:password to the request I simply will be shown a denied request.

I'm using Django Rest Framework. I just want to be able to send this values and other values via GET or POST, PUT, DELETE when making a request via HTTP.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

the answer is [http://username:password@domain.com/api/user/](http://username%3apassword@domain.com/api/user/) that way i can access the API via HTTP